NextJS and Framer Motion webpage layout is not the default size in smaller screen
When i view my webpage in smaller screen it looks like this 
and my index.jsx looks like this
import React from "react";
import Banner from "@/components/Banner";

function Home() {
  return (
    <main className=" ">
      <Banner />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;

and the banner components is like this
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Link from "next/link";

function Banner() {
  return (
    <section className="bg-[url('/1.jpg')] h-screen bg-no-repeat bg-cover relative">
      <div className="h-full w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-[#8a8dc5] via-[#14457b00] to-[#4383e8]"></div>
      <div className="flex justify-center w-full h-full md:w-auto md:h-auto absolute top-[15%] md:left-[15%]">
        <div className="max-w-xl p-10">
          <motion.div
            initial={{ x: "50%", opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.7, ease: "easeInOut", delay: 0 }}
          >
            <div className="py-2 px-3  inline-block tracking-wider rounded bg-purple-200 text-purple-500  font-semibold">
              <p className="text-sm md:text-base">PASSION FOR CARING</p>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
          <motion.div
            initial={{ x: "50%", opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.7, ease: "easeInOut", delay: 0.3 }}
            className="my-5"
          >
            <p className="uppercase font-bold text-2xl md:text-4xl tracking-widest">
              Reliable & High-Quality Health Care Services
            </p>
          </motion.div>
          <motion.div
            initial={{ x: "50%", opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.7, ease: "easeInOut", delay: 0.6 }}
          >
            <p className="text-slate-900 text-sm md:text-base">
              CleanMed Health Care Corporation is a newly organized company
              engaged in delivering high-quality healthcare services.
            </p>
          </motion.div>
          <motion.div
            initial={{ x: "50%", opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.7, ease: "easeInOut", delay: 0.9 }}
            className="mt-5"
          >
            <Link
              target="_blank"
              href="https://cleanmedhealthcare.com/"
              className="bg-purple-600 ease-in duration-150 hover:bg-purple-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded"
            >
              Learn More +
            </Link>
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Banner;

i hope some one can help me im new in Framer motion
i have another components where i use framer motion but i commented those components and leave the banner but it sill looks like that

To address the issue of unwanted white space when animating an element from off-screen, you need to ensure that the container of the element does not allow for overflow. You can achieve this by using CSS to hide the overflow of the container.

There is no width styling on either the main element or the parent section element of banner. Likely you need to add a w-full in one or both of these places.
The browser tools are good for this

If you open dev tools and hover elements in the </> Elements tab you can see what their width is and easily tell if an element is not the full width of the screen.
If its not that, I thought it may be to do with the bg-contain or bg-no-repeat. But, those look correct to me

i did your suggestion but it's still the same i guess the cause is the framer motion the other page are fine when reloading it if it not much of a trouble can you copy my code and try it in yours

i think it has something to with the length of the text it start with 50% in x axis and opacity 0 when it starts animating the opacity will change to 1 and the text will appear 50% in x axis that's why it shows the white spaces in the side

Sorry I don't have time to copy the code and test it in mine. I would have to spin up a next project to do that. I have  work to do. Yeah perhaps it is that animation, what does that animation do? Perhaps there is a different way to do it. What happens if you remove  that animation? (karma pls, im farming)

ok now i have the answer thank your time to comment
the initial style of the text starts  in 50% of the page lets say the text has a width of 1200px when it starts animating the text will show in the 50% of the page with 1200px width thats why there are spaces off the page.
the solution is having the parent tag have a class of overflow-hidden or overflow-clip this way it will disregard the blank spaces where the text starts
